# MEF doesn't import root exe parts

Tags: c#, .net, mef, ioc-container

I'm creating composition container using root DirectoryCatalog.

```
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(".");
Bootstrapper.CompositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(catalog, true);
```

My executable is "Main.exe"
2 issues:

1. Main.exe is not a list of probed files, how do I include it in a list?
2. All other references probed, is there any way to filter list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the first part of your question you can use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833475%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which accepts a search filter for files

```
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(".", "My.Company*.dll"); // asemblies to load
```

To load both *.exe and *.dll do:

```
 var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
 catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(".")); // load only *.dll's
 catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(".", "*.exe")); // load *.exe

 Bootstrapper.CompositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(catalog, true);
```